# Skip redirecting to login page when authenticating via /oauth/authorize

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a use case where the user should be authenticated via /oauth/authorize by entering his username and password into a custom login form which is posted directly without redirecting the user to a providers login page. Authorization code flow seems fitting but how can I alter the flow to skip the redirect to login page? Which are the Spring Oauth2 extension points to customize?

Answer (score 0):

You can have two requests instead of one. You do a `POST` to your login endpoint as an `XMLHttpRequest` and on success you direct the user to the `/oauth/authorize` endpoint.

If you own the client server you might also consider the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow.

Comment: Thanks, I did this by customizing the AuthenticationSuccessHandler. Works for me.